# Why does the complexity of (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ...) = loglogN?

Tags: algorithm

N * (½ + ⅓ + ⅕ + … ) = O(NloglogN)

Why does the complexity of (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ...) = loglogN? I don't understand

Here is the code:

```
void sieve(int N) {
    bool isPrime[N+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= N;++i) {
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }
    isPrime[0] = false;
    isPrime[1] = false;
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= N; ++i) {
         if(isPrime[i] == true) {
             // Mark all the multiples of i as composite numbers
             for(int j = i * i; j <= N ;j += i)
                 isPrime[j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)

Comment: Don't understand either. As written, there appears no N in the sum how could it be log log N? Instead the infinite sum diverges.

Comment: (Limit for) Order of growth - complexity is nowhere in the picture given.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem primes get rarer as numbers get larger, so the density at n is approximately ln(n). So one way to roughly approximate your problem is to turn it into an integral, where you want the integral from x=1 to x=n of 1/(x ln(x)). I think the derivative of ln(ln(x)) is (1/ln(x))*(1/x) = 1/(x ln(x)) so I think that if this approximation is valid the integral is going to be O(ln(ln(n)) - which gets the answer you are looking for.